# Definition of Information Density

Tags: definition

please explain what information density means. I've seen this term used to describe hexadecimal numbers, but I'm uncertain of what it means by itself and in relation to number systems:hexadecimal, binary, decimal, etc. Thank you.

Comment: I think this should be asked on software engineering, not stack overflow. But a small answer for you is how much information can be derived from a single symbol. Here is an example of a hex = dec = binary equality: `f = 15 = 1111`. in this case, `f`represents as much information as `1111` but it uses one symbol vs four.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/numeral-system-information-density, likely off-topic on SO since it doesn't specifically relate to programming